# Hive lookup table filling null value

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have a table trial where I have my main data with two columns geo_cd and channel_id where some values of geo_cd are null. I have another lookup table channel to fill up these null values, I have used the query-:

```
(select t.channel_id,t.geo_cd
 from trial t join
      channel c
      on t.channel_id=c.channel_id
);
```

but I am still getting Null values in channel_id.

Kinldy help.

Comment: That query *cannot* produce `NULL` values for `channel_id`.  There is an inner join on `channel_id`, so `NULL` values would be filtered out.  You should show a more representative query.

Comment: Can you help me with the query, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NVL() function

```
select t.channel_id, nvl(t.geo_cd, c.geo_cd) as geo_cd
 from trial t 
        left join channel c on t.channel_id=c.channel_id
```